# WPF Binding: How to databind to Grid?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, grid, binding

I have created a class `Account`.
Next, I have created another class `ReorderWindowController` which has a field/property `SelectedAccount` of type `Account`.

Finally, I have written `ReorderWindow` WPF window xaml file:

```
<Window ...

    <Window.Resources>

        <contollers:ReorderWindowController x:Key="WindowController" />

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type entities:Account}">
            <Grid Width="140" Height="50" Margin="5">
                <TextBlock Text="Some awesome text" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                <TextBlock Text="Even more awesome text" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>

    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid 
            Name="AccountGrid" 
            DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=WindowController},
                          Path=SelectedAccount}">
        </Grid>
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

When I run my code, `AccountGrid` is not showing anything. Why? How do I make object data bind to the `Grid` and how do I make it use my data template? Thanks.

Comment: Have you implemented INotifyPropertyChanged on your Account and ReorderWindowController classes? Data binding relies on System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged to recieve notification of changes, which causes binding to retrieve value.

Comment: Yes I did. Though the problem I am facing isn't really related to the changes notification, thanks for the heads-up.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of a Grid use a ContentPresenter like this:

```
<Grid>         
<ContentPresenter
Name="AccountGrid"              
Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=WindowController},                           Path=SelectedAccount}">  
   </ContentPresenter>
</Grid>
```