# C# wpf grid binding and child elements

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

Is it possible to bind the object to the grid element and then bind properties of this object to child elements?
Let's take a class Person as an example:

```
class Person {
   public string FirstName {get;set;}
   public string LastName {get; set;}
}
```

Is it possible to define binding like this:

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding Path=Person}" >
      <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding FirstName}" /> 
      <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding LastName}" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Is this is theoretical question? What happened when you tried?

Comment: "Is it possible to bind the object to the grid element and then bind properties of this object to child elements"...Yes. "Is it possible to define binding like this?"....there are easier ways handling it from the back end.

Comment: @Adam "there are easier ways handling it from the back end". Can you share an example?

Comment: Here check this out: front-end binding so I don't even have to explain a back end binding: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493445/wpf-binding-how-to-databind-to-grid

Comment: @ijon, what do you want to do exactly?

Comment: @Ugur I want to define several grid elements in order to display data of contact persons. Grid has two columns. In first line I want to display first name and last name of first person. In second line - email and phone number, Then in third line first name and last name of second person and so on. There are max. 3 contact person.

Comment: @ijon, then why don't you use DataGrid. You can easily  assign your data

Comment: @Ugur. Because the data I want to display are different type. Also I want to change style (font size, font weight) for first and second line.

Comment: And... Have you run into any problem? Or were you just asking in advance? This is indeed possible, there could be other ways depending on your needs, but for what you're describing, your solution is as good as any. Of course, you could simply do `Text="{Binding Person.FirstName}"`...